# Vary angular route by host for multi-tenant client app

Tags: angularjs, multi-tenant

I am designing a multi-tenant application where the tenant is defined by the url host (eg tenant1.myapp.com, tenant2.myapp.com, etc).

Can I vary my angular route by host name?
eg, a typical route would be:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/index.html"
});
```

how would I vary this by hostname, eg:

```
$routeProvider.when("/login", {
    controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/{host}/index.html"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... It is not Angular-way of doing things. You do not have access to `$location` service in the phase when routes are defined. You have only access to `$locationProvider`, which is later used by `$location` (See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

But I guess that you could perhaps do it by accessing the global window scope and read the absolute url. Then you would define your routes differently based on this absolute url.

Something like this

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('/tenant1/')) {
 $routeProvider.when("/sport/:id", { templateUrl: "sport-detail.html", controller: "SportDetailCtrl" });
} else {
 $routeProvider.when("/sport/modification/:id", { templateUrl: "sport-detail.html", controller: "SportDetailCtrl" });
}
```